# How to populate word/fill Word from multiple tables using Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word, office-interop

I'm an Access novice; I customized the code below. The problem is it prints the primary key instead of the name of the field referred to.

For example, in one statement I want Institution Name to be printed in Word but instead it returns the primary key from a particula rinstitute in my table.

> `FormFields("txtNQFLevel").Result = Me.NQFLLEVEL` I would like this field from another table but in the same query to return string values referred not its opposite primary key value
>
> `FormFields("txtInstitute").Result = Me.Institute_Name` I would like this field which is from another table but in the same query to return string values referred not its opposite primary key value

```
Function BursaryContractYear2()
    Dim appWord As Word.Application
    Dim doc As Word.Document
    Dim Path As String

    On Error Resume Next
    Error.Clear

    Path = "C:\Users\Motlatsi Motlhamme\Desktop\FillWordAccess.docx "
    Set appWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set appWord = New Word.Application
        appWord.Visible = True
    End If

    Set doc = appWord.Documents.Open(Path, , True)
    With doc
        .FormFields("txtFirstName").Result = Me.FIRST_NAMES
        .FormFields("txtSurname").Result = Me.SURNAME
        .FormFields("txtNQFLevel").Result = Me.NQFLLEVEL
        .FormFields("txtInstitute").Result = Me.Institute_Name
        appWord.Visible = True
        appWord.Activate
    End With

    Set doc = Nothing
    Set appWord = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: It's best not to use `On Error Resume Next`... in general, but especially while troubleshooting a problem.  You're telling VBA is ignore all errors.

Comment: You don't provide enough information. What is `Me.`? Is it a Form?

Answer (score 0):

The data being inserted into the `txtInstitute` field in the Word document is `Me.Institute_Name`. `Me` refers to the context the VBA code is running in, which your question doesn't identify. However, the fact that you are getting primary keys in your Word document suggests that `Institute_Name` is the name of a column in the table bound to the current Access context, which contains a foreign key to an `Institutes` table.

In Access, it might look like the `Institute_Field` column contains a name, not a primary key. Access calls this a [lookup field](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-lookup-field-87e84cbd-d60c-4473-8a98-3e391c42f239). Lookup fields can be easier to understand than the traditional database concept, [foreign keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key). But when you're working under the hood of a lookup field, eventually you need to understand the foreign key relationship that Access has been hiding from you.

If the name you want is found in the `Name` column of the `Institutes` table, you can probably fix your code by changing that line to:

```
.FormFields("txtInstitute").Result = DLookup("Name", "Institutes", "ID = " & Me.Institute_Name)
```

If you need to perform this procedure many times, you should be aware that it is inefficient because of the [N+1 SELECT query issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-select-query-issue). The more efficient way to achieve this result is to ensure that `Me` is bound to a context, like a [joined table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)), which contains the data you want.